# Error removing file /home/diba/Downloads/Postman/snapshot_blob.bin: Permission denied

Tags: postman, ubuntu-18.04

I downloaded postman app on ubuntu 18.04 to test my api and in the installing process I ran into a problem, so I tried to delete the package which by the way I deleted the archive from my home directory using:

> sudo rm -rf postman.tar.gz

but the main package can't be deleted and when I tried to move it to trash I ran into this error -->

> Error removing file /home/aaaa/Downloads/Postman/snapshot_blob.bin:
> Permission denied.

I have tried these commands below

> sudo apt-get purge postman
>
> sudo apt-get remove postman
>
> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove postman

but stil no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run as root. It has more privileges than sudo.